# Why the data inserted for specified time smaller than current time still cannot be inserted in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask, when using `insert into` to insert data for a specified time in Apache IoTDB, and the time specified is smaller than the current time, but an error popped out: `SQL Error [607] [lnsertion time [2023-08-10T14:05:54.774+08:00[Asia/Shanghai] is less than ttl time bound [2023-08-21T17:08:28.792+08:00[Asia/Shanghai]]`. Can this data still be inserted and how should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This writing task exceeds the range of ttl in Apache IoTDB. It seems that you have set a ttl of 1 hour, so if you insert data before 1 hour, an error will be reported. See if you can change the settings of ttl and try again.